# Dropdown selection not registered by Chrome's undo functionality

Tags: angular, typescript, google-chrome

I have a custom input component that extends a text input by a dropdown list with suggestions based on previous user input. When I select different suggestions subsequently and then use Chrome's undo feature by ***pressing CTRL+Z, it concatenates the previous string rather than replacing the current string*** in the field.

*For instance, when I first select the suggestion "AAA", then remove it, then select "BBB" and press CTRL+Z, the input contains the string "BBBAAA".*

So it seems that the string insertion from the dropdown menu is not registered by Chrome as a modification to the DOM on the undo stack. As the last registered action was removing the string, the undo function just concatenates it to the current one.

*This happens in Chrome and Internet Explorer 11, in Firefox I don't have any problems.*

---

I tried ***suppressing the CTRL+Z undo feature*** for the given input with a Custom Directive:

```
@HostListener('keydown', ['$event']) onKeyDown(e: KeyboardEvent) {
  if (e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode === 90) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
}
```

However, I can still undo the changes of the input by pressing CTRL+Z in another input field, so I would have to disable the undo feature for the whole site.

How can I ***tell Chrome to add the input change to its undo stack***?

Here is the simple callback function by the dropdown input that updates the value when a dropdown item is selected:

```
(contact) => {
  if (this.formGroup) {
    this.formGroup.patchValue(contact);
  }
}
```

Replacing `patchValue()` by `setValue()` does not seem to make any difference, nor does calling `this.formGroup.markAsTouched();`.